# Change resolution using browser extension

Tags: javascript, resolution, assistive

**The Problem:** The new WCAG 2.1 Reflow Success Criterion requires pages to reflow and be functional down to 320 CSS pixels. Now my machine has 1600px width which means I can enlarge print to 500% (1600/5)=320. Now browsers tend to jump by bigger increments as magnification increases. Chrome is typical. It has enlargement steps: 110%, 125%, 150%, 175%, 200%, 250%, 300%, 400% and 500%. Users with low vision could benefit with smaller increments between 300% and 500%. It actually more important to get the exact size you need in large print than with smaller.

**Question:** Is there a way to set the resolution from the client application or from assistive technology that is a browser extension? Are there zoom work arounds that an extension could perform?

Comment: Check out CSS `transform: scale()` ... it might help you

Comment: It is unclear what **technical** problem you are trying to solve. Please be more specific and not too broad.